# How to add a second model

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm trying to make an animation requiring 2 characters on Blender.

The two models have some controls that adjust their facial expressions, yet when I append the second model into blender, both models lose those controls. What do I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: hard to say, it could perhaps depend on how thay are controlled (I guess animated shape keys), and on how you append... do they use identically named resources ? (just guessing) does it happens if you append to a a new clean file the secondo model, or the other, or then both?

Comment: please share your .blend file to be able to assist you.